# Webpack is unable to find imports that TypeScript (apparently) finds

Tags: typescript, webpack, box2d

Background: I started from the (works fine for me) [ASP.NET Core example of SignalR and webpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).
My goal is to use [this TypeScript library](https://github.com/flyover/box2d.ts) to do client-side interpolation for a multiplayer game that's server-side authoritative.

The reason I think the issue is webpack-related is that VisualStudio has intellisense for the box2d.ts library, and tsc reports no errors when run on its own.

This is my first project with webpack and TypeScript, so apologies if I've missed something obvious.

**The error reported by webpack:**

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Box2D' in 
'C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 2:0-31 3:14-26
```

**UPDATE: Error with verbose output:**

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Box2D' in 'C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src'
resolve 'Box2D' in 'C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\src doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\src doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\src doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nathan.b\src doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\nathan.b\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\src doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\src doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src
        using description file: C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\package.json (relative path: ./src/Box2D)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/Box2D)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D is not a file
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules\Box2D doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D.js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules\Box2D.js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D.ts doesn't exist
              C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules\Box2D.ts doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules\Box2D doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D\index
                  using description file: C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\package.json (relative path: ./src/Box2D/index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D\index doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D\index.js doesn't exist
                    .ts
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D\index.ts doesn't exist
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\src]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\node_modules]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\src]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\node_modules]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\src]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\node_modules]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\src]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\node_modules]
[C:\Users\src]
[C:\Users\node_modules]
[C:\src]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules\Box2D]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D.js]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules\Box2D.js]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D.ts]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\node_modules\Box2D.ts]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D\index]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D\index.js]
[C:\Users\nathan.b\Desktop\Gamey\Gamey\src\Box2D\index.ts]
 @ ./src/index.ts 2:0-31 3:14-26
```

**index.ts:**
*Just enough to make sure nothing is compiled out.*

```
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
import * as box2d from "Box2D";

const g: box2d.b2Vec2 = new box2d.b2Vec2(0, -10)
console.log(g);

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub")
    .build();
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "Box2D": [ "./Box2D/Box2D" ]
    }
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot"),
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(["wwwroot/*"]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].[chunkhash].css"
        })
    ]
};
```

**Project structure:**
[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After reading up on webpack module resolution](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/), another solution is to switch from module references to either absolute or relative path references.

**Changes:**
**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "..",
    "paths": {
      "Box2D": [ "./src/Box2D/Box2D" ]
    }
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**
Leave the same as in the question - no modification needed.

**index.ts:**

```
import * as box2d from "./Box2D/Box2D";
```

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got it working. I had to explicitly reference the Box2D library path. No glob variant worked (/* or **/*), but maybe I'm missing something there.

**The change:**

```
resolve: {
    modules: ['./src/Box2D', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
},
```